# how to spawn 1 to 3 objects randomly many times Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to spawn 1 to 3 monsters randomly many times in Javascript, this is the code i have for now but this only makes it randomly spawn when i refresh and then it keeps spawning the same amount of monsters the whole time.

```js
function spawnMonster(){   
  setInterval(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < randomMonster; i++){
      monsterDiv.innerHTML += monsterPic;
      outputDiv.innerHTML = "monstrene angriper.</br>" + outputDiv.innerHTML;
    }
  }, Math.floor(Math.random()* 3000) + 1000);
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the whole code? It is not understandable what are you trying to do.

Comment: What is `randomMonster`? Where is that set?

Comment: the whole code is very long, i am trying to find a way to spawn 1 to 3 monster images with random timing in javascript and i dont know how to do it. i can paste the whole code if you want but it is very long. @AvetikNersisyan

Comment: randomMonster is just a variable, var randomMonster = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1; @esqew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `randomMonster` is the random value between 1-3.

When the variable is set, it (obviously) doesn't change as you did describe.

Just make sure you calculate a new `randomMonster` -value inside the `setInterval` function:

```js
function spawnMonster(){
  setInterval(function(){
    const randomMonster = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < randomMonster; i++){ 
      monsterDiv.innerHTML += monsterPic; 
      outputDiv.innerHTML = "monstrene angriper.</br>" + outputDiv.innerHTML;
    }
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 1000);
}
```

Comment: thank you, this worked. i had done the same thing but i had the var randomMonster = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1; outside the function, should i have two randomMonster variables or only one inside the setInterval function?

Comment: If you are using `randomMonster` in multiple places (and it needs to be recalculated each time), maybe a function returning the random value is a better choice.